# Symbolic Weak Form

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, finite-element-method

Usually I write the weak form by hand for my FEM code, but it's a little annoying and mechanic sometimes.

So, I wonder, is there any way to generate the *symbolic weak form* in Mathematica? For instance, if I have this strong form:

$$\nabla\cdot(\nabla u) = f$$

I'd like to have an automation of multiplying by a shape function $\phi$, and integrating it obtaining

$$\nabla \phi \ \nabla u = \phi f$$

So the procedure is as follows.

- take the left hand side and left-multiply with $\phi$: $\phi \;  (\nabla\cdot(\nabla u))$
- integrate by parts (usually): $\int \phi \;  (\nabla\cdot(\nabla u)) = \int \nabla\phi \cdot \nabla u - \int_\partial \phi \cdot \nabla u$
- by definition $\phi$ is zero on the boundary $\int_\partial \phi \cdot \nabla u = 0$
- hence only the left hand side (integrated) remains $\int \nabla\phi \cdot \nabla u$

The very same procedure could be applied to the right hand side.

This would be great to achieve symbolically, as I am planning to implement a FEM software, not using `NDSolve` or other functions.

The top would be even generating the symbolic sum with Jacobians and Gauss integration points, but this is maybe asking too much! 
In a very classical FEM formulation, as [for instance here in deal.II](http://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_3.html) for a simple Laplace problem, $u$ and $\phi$ are just interpolated with a shape function, for instance $\phi$ itself, as $u(x) = \sum_j U_j \phi_j(x)$. The integral is then reduced to a sum of integrals over a *triangulated domain*, but as I said, I'd be glad to just extract the weak form in general (not just for linear problems, but also for instance for $\nabla \cdot ( A(x) \nabla u) = -f$ for a general $A(x)$.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should add example(s) i.e. desired input, output, etc. for others to play with. Also, it's better to link materials explaining what's "weak form" in the question.

Comment: I've tried to explain better @xzczd, but MathJax is not working apparently.

Comment: Well, there's no doubt that MathJax is supported in this site. See my edit for your question as an example.

Comment: Thanks for editing, the side-help said `MathJax equations $\sin^2 \theta$`, now I know I need double dollar signs. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, give us an example in which you did the transformation by hand and it will be much easier to figure out how to do the operation in *Mathematica*.

Comment: What type of application do you have in mind? Is this purely educational, do you hope to solve a problem that `NDSolve` can not solve? Or is there another reason altogether?

Comment: Do you want to use `NDSolve` / Mathematica as a pre-processor for deal.II ?

Comment: I've just edited the question with steps, and clarifying that I don't plan to use `NDSolve`.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at AceGen/AceFEM. It is a FEM toolbox for Mathematica. It uses AD to derive the element system of equations. http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si