Integration by parts for Green's first identity
How should one implement
$$\int _{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,d\Omega \ =\ \int _{\Gamma }v\,\nabla u\cdot {\hat {\mathbf {n} }}\,d\Gamma -\int _{\Omega }v\,\nabla ^{2}u\,d\Omega\,,$$
Symbolically for an example? I don't want to do numerical integration but rather give the information of the left hand side and get the right hand side of the equation above.

Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133575/1871
